# Javascript loaded through ajax cannot call functions in later script blocks

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, script-tag, domready

I have 2 HTML files, **1.html** and **2.html**.

- **1** is the main page, which loads **2** by ajax and stuff its content into a `div`.
- In **1**, there are 3 script blocks - **A**, **B**, and **C**.

  - The `$(document).ready()` in block **B** calls a function in block **C**.
  - There are no errors.
- In **2**, there are 3 script blocks - **P**, **Q**, and **R**.

  - The `$(document).ready()` in block **Q** calls a function in block **R**.
  - It gives an error.

It seems that when some Javascript is loaded through ajax, it cannot call functions in a script block that appears later (but not earlier) in the same file. Why? Is this expected behaviour?

### Source code

#### 1.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script block A -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function A() {alert('A');}
</script>

<div>x</div>

<!-- Script block B -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        A(); B(); C();

        $("#ajax_load_result").load("2.html");
    });

    function B() {alert('B');}
</script>

<div>x</div>

<!-- Script block C -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function C() {alert('C');}
</script>

<div id='ajax_load_result'>y</div>
```

#### 2.html

```
<div>x</div>

<!-- Script block P -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function P() {alert('P');}
</script>

<div>x</div>

<!-- Script block Q -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        P(); Q(); R();
    });

    function Q() {alert('Q');}
</script>

<div>x</div>

<!-- Script block R -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function R() {alert('R');}
</script>

<div>x</div>
```

### Output

It alerts `A`, `B`, `C`, `P`, `Q`, then gives an error message.

### Error messages

Opera 12.11:

> Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: R

Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: R is not defined

IE 9:

> SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'R' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192012/how-does-scope-work-with-multiple-script-tags-for-javascript-in-an-html-docume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.html $(document).ready fires immediately because the dom has already been built and at that point the script block containing R hasn't been reached yet and hence R is not defined. In 1.html the whole page loads before $(document).ready therefore C get defined.

Comment: Now I see. (I used to think `.ready()` would be called after **2** is "completedly" loaded).