# What's happening when I add more <script> tags?

Tags: javascript

I am adding some third party code to my page. This is the code sample they supply which works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script>
    Munchkin.init('123-ABC-456');
</script>
```

I thought I would remove some tags and turned it into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    Munchkin.init('381-KZC-440');
</script>
```

This now doesn't work, stating that `Munchkin` is not defined. I did a look around and [read about scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192012/how-does-scope-work-with-multiple-script-tags-for-javascript-in-an-html-docume) but I'm still confused as to why it breaks, the order has been kept the same. If I had to guess I would say that the JS file being called is allowed to load completely before the page continues onto the next script tag, whereas in my version it continues too quickly. If so, this could presumably be used for many advantages as it's essentially an "onloadcomplete" event?

Comment: Is there any reason you do use `document.write()` to insert a hardcoded `<script>` tag?

Comment: Other than it's the code I was provided with, didn't inspect it to think about changing it all, now you've pointed it out I might do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new script won't be loaded until the current script block terminates. Think about it like this: The first code will result in a DOM structure like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(...;
</script>
<script src='//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js'></script>
<script>
    Munchkin.init('123-ABC-456');
</script>
```

As you can see, the script is inserted *after* the script that calls `document.write`. Therefore the script is loaded when the third script element is evaluated.

But if you have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(...);
    Munchkin.init('123-ABC-456');
</script>
<script src='//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js'></script>
```

then you are trying to access the object before the script was loaded.

Comment: Ohh! that's very well explained. As @Sirko mentioned, why don't I just take it out of the JS and hardcode the `<script src='//munchkin...`, well I tried that and it works as normal. I appreciate it's someone else's code, but can you think why they might have supplied it this way and not simply hardcoded?

Comment: Given that particular example, I cannot think of a reason, no.