# Included page javascript scope

Tags: javascript, xml, spring, eclipse, jsp

I am working on a spring project. We have nested included pages. Some are pure jsp, some are pure js, and some are a mix of both. We are using the JSP taglibrary. We have a page which currently while working, has pretty poor performance, Im talking about taking 30 seconds to load at times. So I have been attempting to address this performance issue. This particular page deals with profiles and is rather involved and complex. Needless to say that the approach taken was to have all the pages loaded at once and flip between them using sections. This was largely because making changes in one section/tab would affect other tabs. If this was all managed on the server side it wouldnt have been an issue.

I noticed that the profiles which seem to have the worst performance, always had multiple addresses, and when counting the number of dom elements, a freshly created profile has around 10k, the average around 40k, but the slow profiles have over 90k, and most of the difference tends to be in the number of addresses listed. So I figured I would tackle that and see the results.

I got a sample section of code working on its own page. Three dropdowns, one for country, province, and city. Selecting the country populates province and so on. The original page is using ajax calls to populate all these, which means a lot of back and forth. So for my approach I loaded a single XML file containing all that information.

My problem is that when I try to load the country.xml it fails. The pure js pages do not recongize the JSP taglibrary command which sets the path to the resource, and when I move only that section to a higher page, the function throws null errors from the variable that should be holding the xml data.

So here is how it works on the sample page

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "<c:url value='/resources/xml/country.xml' />", true);
xmlhttp.send();
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 


$(document).ready(function(){
        loadA();
        loadB();
        loadC();
    });

function loadA(){}
function loadB(){}
function loadC(){}
```

I have that working, but when I attempt to break it apart onto multiple pages I get `SCRIPT5009: xmlhttp is undefined` and `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference`.

My first objective was to get the countries loaded from the XML before moving down since everything is dependent on the one above. So below is the original construction which is working.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-md-3"> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label"><spring:message code="label.country" /></label>
                                        <form:select id="CCountry_${vs.index}" path="residences[${vs.index}].country" cssClass="form-control" onchange="countryChange(this, {selectOneLabel: '${selectOne}', otherProvLabel : '${otherProv}', otherCitylabel : '${otherCity}'});">
                                            <form:option value=""><spring:message code="select.one"/></form:option>
<form:options items="${countryCtbl}" itemValue="codeValue" itemLabel="comboDescVal" />                                      
                                        </form:select>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And here is my modification

```
<div class="row" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-md-3"> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label"><spring:message code="label.country" /></label>
                                        <form:select id="CCountry_${vs.index}" path="residences[${vs.index}].country" cssClass="form-control" onchange="countryChange(this, {selectOneLabel: '${selectOne}', otherProvLabel : '${otherProv}', otherCitylabel : '${otherCity}'});">
                                            <form:option value=""><spring:message code="select.one"/></form:option>
<script>countryRefresh(document.getElementById('CCountry_${vs.index}'));</script>                                   
                                        </form:select>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

and here in the included js page is the new function

```js
function countryRefresh(documentId)
    {
        var countries = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName(documentId);

        for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            //loop to populate selection box
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = countries[i].getElementsByTagName("CountryName")[0].textContent;
            option.value = countries[i].getElementsByTagName("CountryId")[0].textContent;
            mybox.options.add(option);
        }
    }
```

To me this seems like the JS in a higher page is not being called or the scopes are different. Since I cant restructure the entire page, how can I get my xmlDoc to the area I need it? I am aware that with minimal effort I could recreate the JS page as a JSP page, but I feel that is the wrong approach.

I found that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192012/6891471) was similar in nature to mine but was different as it was the same page and mine is across different pages.
This [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/If-I-have-two-or-more-JavaScript-files-on-my-webpage-will-the-variables-for-one-JavaScript-file-apply-for-all-JavaScript-files) also seems to indicate that what I am trying to do should work.

Comment: Your XMLHttpRequest request is not correct. You are reading the responseXML before it comes back.

Comment: @epascarello I got that code directly form W3Schools so I dont see how it could be wrong (unless they are wrong?). Heres the example I took it from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app

Comment: Your code and the link you posted is different. That code uses a synchronous call (which is bad) and you use a broken asynchronous code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest